# List of symbols and units under an equation

Tags: spacing, equations, lists, nomenclature

I have many equations in my report and want to add a list (like the one shown below) below all of my equations (not a separate nomenclature list at the end). Kind of like a mini-nomenclature. Also would be nice if the units ended at the same point.

[image]

Is there anyway to do this? Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a tabular could help?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

text
%
\[
  A+B=1
\]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXr}
A & this & m/s\\
B & that & s\\
\end{tabularx}

text
\end{document}
```

[image]